# Another way to compute the flux?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, spheres, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

I have to compute $\iint F \cdot \hat{N}dS$ of the half sphere $z^2+x^2+y^2=1$ and $z>0$ with $F=(-y,x,x^2+z)$.

I computed the flux by closing the surface with $x^2+y^2=1$ and got an answer $\frac{11 \pi}{12}$ which is correct. My question is. Could I instead use Stokes theorem? I know I can try, but if the answer is yes, then i will give it a try!

Thanks.

Comment: You used divergence theorem and then subtracted flux through the disc?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean apply Stokes' theorem. Are you asking whether you can find flux through direct surface integral? If so, yes you can.

Comment: 1. Yes I used divergence and then subtracted flux through the disc.

Comment: 2. I mean, could I instead use $\iint Curl (F) \hat{n} dS$?

Comment: No you cannot use curl. It is not the same as flux of the given vector field. However you can use direct surface integral if you want.